# Snap instantly to top of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to instantly snap to the top of the page without scrolling, when pressing a button? I saw that there are a few ways to scroll to the top, but they are always kinda smooth-scroll.

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0,0);`

Comment: Make the button an `<a>` element with `href=#`?

Comment: Yeah I tried this, but it scrolls smootly, I need it to jump instanly with no scroll-animaton.

Comment: What browser are you using? If you have smooth scrolling enabled it may cause this, try use a different browser/device on the same page and see if the behaviour is the same in which case it may be scroll easing caused by a library you're using.

Comment: Oh! scroll-behaviour was on smooth. Changed it to auto, now it works like a charme!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
// the button is stored in the variable topScroll
// the first parameter in scrollTo is x axis and second is y
topScroll.onclick = () => window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, 0);

//If you don't want to manipulate scrollX
topScroll.onclick = () => window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, 0);
```

tell me if this works

Comment: Sadly not, it scrolls to the top, but I need it to jump with no animation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  
  // We get the Container Element, to prepend some random Elements to increase the Length.
  const containerEl = document.getElementById('container')
  
  // Loop to insert 100 paragraph elements with random Number
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    const newEl = document.createElement('p');
    newEl.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
    
    containerEl.prepend(newEl);
  }
  
  // We create a Header Element for the Top page
  const titleEl = document.createElement("h1");
  titleEl.innerText = "U.S.S Enterprise";
  containerEl.prepend(titleEl);
  
  // We jump to the bottom of the Page
  const containerHeight = containerEl.offsetHeight;
  window.scrollTo(0, containerHeight);
  
  // We add a EventListener for the Button at the bottom of the Page
  document.getElementById('scrollTopBtn').addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // When clicked, we jump to the top of the page
    // The User can set a default Behavior for scrolling in the Browser as Accessability 
    // Setting. If you dont override it, it defaults to auto and using this browser set 
    // Setting. Therefore we define the behavior as instant.
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'instant'
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="scrollTopBtn">Beam me up, Scotty!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: behavior only accepts 'auto' or 'smooth', 'instant' isn't a possible option.

Comment: @dantheman Oh snap!, thats true. I've looked at the Doc for `Element.scrollTo()`, where it is available. My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'instant'
    });

Actually this part worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use this function when user click the button:

```js
function scrollToTop(){
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```